# What is browsertools://browsertools.library.js?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

Is this browsertools://browsertools.library.js - only for IE ?

This is interfering execution of my scripts. Is there any way I can stop browsertools://browsertools.library.js - interfering my scripts.

Please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: That's the F12 developer tools. Are your scripts not running correctly with the developer tools open?

Comment: @BoltClock - yes those are running correctly with F12 - developer tools. It's problem only when developer tools are turned off.